# Parsing of the page

Tags: python, json, parsing, web, beautifulsoup

everybody, I need to get the factual currency values from this URL

Here is the link

https://p2p.binance.com/ru/trade/sell/USDT?fiat=EUR&payment=Wise

Attaching the website for

And her is the screenshot of the website with actual  to parse and values [The website picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrVxY.png)

I tried this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://p2p.binance.com/ru/trade/sell/USDT?fiat=EUR&payment=Wise"

with requests.Session() as session:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(url).content)
    # extract the product code - used in the POST request
    product_code = soup.find_all('div', class_='css-ovjtyv',)

    response = session.post(url, data={
    }, headers={
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    })
    print(response)
```

But it didn't work, the main problem is that soup can't find needed divs, i suppose that it is related with dynamicaly loading of the page
Thanks everybody for helping

Comment: if its dynamicaly loading of the page , then use selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is loading the data from external URL. You can use next example to load the data to pandas DataFrame:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "https://p2p.binance.com/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search"

# modify the payload to obtain customized results:
payload = {
    "asset": "USDT",
    "countries": [],
    "fiat": "EUR",
    "page": 1,
    "payTypes": ["Wise"],
    "publisherType": None,
    "rows": 10,
    "tradeType": "SELL",
}

data = requests.post(url, json=payload).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

df = pd.DataFrame(d["advertiser"] for d in data["data"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                              userNo realName      nickName margin marginUnit orderCount  monthOrderCount  monthFinishRate  advConfirmTime email registrationTime mobile  userType tagIconUrls  userGrade   userIdentity proMerchant isBlocked
0  s8a2b7011c94a31feb7af0956075d1791     None       BigTeam   None       None       None             1359         0.996334               0  None             None   None  merchant          []          3  MASS_MERCHANT        None      None
1  sb6207d764dd43482be6926940ad9e306     None  _OneMillion_   None       None       None               20         1.000000               0  None             None   None      user          []          2                       None      None
2  sba64098b5fc1336cae7b04004da22936     None      botamart   None       None       None               86         0.693548               0  None             None   None  merchant          []          3  MASS_MERCHANT        None      None
3  s61cf87b68f1f3e899a2eda92b048f0ac     None     Crypto729   None       None       None             1656         1.000000               0  None             None   None  merchant          []          3  MASS_MERCHANT        None      None
4  s13d201eb782c32308a75b480b42b79a7     None      gf_ferre   None       None       None              102         0.971429               0  None             None   None      user          []          2                       None      None
5  s019f6560343a36a4b6890d4c6cfff796     None  valeriia0018   None       None       None              117         0.991525               0  None             None   None      user          []          2                       None      None
6  sc74f15f7c6653b97ba80030b04ec249c     None       Obelisk   None       None       None              350         0.985915               0  None             None   None      user          []          2                       None      None
7  sfd450f1884023e65a5bc4414446bde45     None   korolevskiy   None       None       None             2464         0.989558               0  None             None   None  merchant          []          3  MASS_MERCHANT        None      None
8  s4f1f1b6040f63557843d11d3e8d1824a     None        maks69   None       None       None              582         0.986441               0  None             None   None  merchant          []          3  MASS_MERCHANT        None      None
9  sa43ac46c9240379693be9e0d0e0c5992     None        Daryya   None       None       None               26         0.962963               0  None             None   None      user          []          2                       None      None
```